# Why is the data from the form not getting posted to the PHP file on the host server, when it works fine on the local server?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, post

I am trying to build a simple contact form. When I host the website on my local server the ajax posts the data to the PHP file, and the PHP file is able to get the information. But when I host the website on my host's server the PHP file isn't able to access the posted data. I'm not quite sure why.

JQuery/Ajax:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#contactFormToSubmit").submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    let fullname = $("#nameForm")
      .val()
      .trim();
    let subject = $("#subjForm")
      .val()
      .trim();
    let email = $("#emailForm")
      .val()
      .trim();
    let message = $("#textForm")
      .val()
      .trim();
    let new_form = new FormData();
    new_form.append("fullname", fullname);
    new_form.append("subject", subject);
    new_form.append("emailFrom", email);
    new_form.append("message", message);

    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "contactFormPHP/submitform.php",
      data: new_form,
      contentType: false,
      processData: false,
      cache: false,
      success: function() {
        $("#FormSubmitDiv").append(
          '<div class="alert alert-success text-center alert-dismissible fade show" role="alert"><strong>Submitted successfully! Thank you.</strong><button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button></div>'
        );
        $(".alert-success").fadeOut(10000);
        $("#contactFormToSubmit")[0].reset();
      }
    });
  });
});
```

and PHP:

```
<?php

   use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
   use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\SMTP;
   use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;

   require 'config.php';
   require 'plugins/PHPMailer/src/Exception.php';
   require 'plugins/PHPMailer/src/PHPMailer.php';
   require 'plugins/PHPMailer/src/SMTP.php';

   $to = '*********@gmail.com';  
   if(isset($_POST['fullname'])){
      echo "<script>console.log('It is working properly!');</script>";
   }
   if(!isset($_POST['fullname'])){
      echo "<script>console.log('It is not working properly!');</script>";
   }
   $fullname = $_POST['fullname'];
   
   $subject = $_POST['subject'];
   
   $message = $_POST['message'];
  
   $email_from = $_POST['emailFrom'];
   $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
   $headers .= "From: " .$email_from. "\r\n";
   $headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=UTF-8" . "\r\n";
   function console_log($fullname, $with_script_tags = true) {
      $js_code = 'console.log(' . json_encode($fullname, JSON_HEX_TAG) . 
  ');';
      if ($with_script_tags) {
          $js_code = '<script>' . $js_code . '</script>';
      }
      echo $js_code;
  }
   $mail = new PHPMailer(true);

   try {
      
      $mail->STMPOptions = array(
         'ssl'=> array(
            'verify_peer'=> false,
            'verify_peer_name'=> false,
            'allow_self_signed'=> true, 
         )
      );

      $mail->isSMTP();  
      $mail->SMTPDebug = 2;                                          // Send using SMTP
      $mail->Host       = CONFIG['email']['host'];                // Set the SMTP server to send through
      $mail->SMTPAuth   = true; 
      $mail->Port       = CONFIG['email']['port'];                // Enable SMTP authentication
      $mail->SMTPSecure = CONFIG['email']['SMTPSecure'];         // Enable TLS encryption; `PHPMailer::ENCRYPTION_SMTPS` encouraged
      $mail->Username   = CONFIG['email']['username'];            // SMTP username
      $mail->Password   = CONFIG['email']['password'];            // SMTP password

      //Recipients
      $mail->AddReplyTo($email_from, $fullname);
      
      $mail->setFrom($email_from, $fullname);
      
      $mail->addAddress($to, 'Blue Owl Learning');                            

      // Content
      $mail->isHTML(true);                                       // Set email format to HTML
      $mail->Subject = $subject;
      $mail->Body    = $message;
      $mail->AltBody = strip_tags($message);

      $mail->send();
    
      echo 'Message has been sent';
      
   } 
   catch (Exception $e) {
      echo "Message could not be sent. Mailer Error: {$mail->ErrorInfo}";
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

I was using the .htaccess to change the links. So although there was no clear syntax error, the link I was using was slightly wrong, so changing the url from
`url: "contactFormPHP/submitform.php"`
to
`url: "contactFormPHP/submitform"`
fixed the problem